# Yii Framework - Renaming root directory causes no output

Tags: php, yii, frameworks, mamp, yii-extensions

I am a beginner in PHP Yii framework.I extracted the files for the project "basic" which I downloaded from Yii website, in to my htdocs directory in MAMP.I accessed the project through :/basic/web.

Now I just renamed the project directory to "myproject".Then accessed the project through :/myproject/web
Now it is showing nothing in the output.Why is it happening?.Do I need to change something else, when I change the application directory name.When I rename it back to basic, it is working as expected.
Inviting all #Yii people to comment

Comment: Have you checked apache error_log ?

Comment: It must be `/var/log/apache or httpd/log/`

Answer (score 1):

Check your front-controller file (index.php).
In variable $yii must be real path to framework

Also add the display of all errors in the same:
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

If this does not solve the problem, send the error in the past protected/runtime/application.log